# Making a simple mono wav into a 3D sound with a position

Tags: audio, audacity

Is it possible to take a simple mono sound file and then via some tool or maybe an Audacity effect of some sort turn it into a 3D sound with a specified position in 3D space?

Or is this only possible by recording with actual binural recording equipment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 3D program Blender you can put speakers in 3D space,
but better quality is in sound program Apple Logic: its possible to mess with surround (Its like that don't need surround soundsystem, it's just psychoacustics: 2 speakers is ok)

example you can take mone airplane sample and make automation what sounds like plane is coming from far right to here left, stuf like that